# How to clone & restore virtual box hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, disk-image, acronis-trueimage

What I want to do is to clone my virtual box HDD with dual boot os. XP and Vista.

I'm using Acronis and back it up on a flash drive. And end up with the flash drive that is partitioned. 2 partitions just like the virtual box hard disk. What do I do to restore it.  I'm running Acronis inside virtual box.
What do I do

- to make use of the backup and
  actually restore what I've back up.
- And to be able to boot to XP and Vista again inside virtual box.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have multiple issues going on...

First off, you don't really need to use something like Acronis inside your VM to get a complete backup. By far the easiest way is to just shutdown the VM and make a copy of the associated .VDI file for the virtual hard disk (usually found in %USERPROFILE%.VirtualBox\HardDisks). I prefer to use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) to compress them, as it generally can reduce the drive size by at least half.

As for the flash drive itself, it sounds like you told Acronis to duplicate the virtual hard drive directly to the flash drive itself. The reverse procedure (select flash drive as source, virtual hard drive as destination) should give you what you want, though you will want to make sure the VM has captured the drive or mount it as a RAW / pass-thru VDI directly to the flash drive itself.

Comment: no, I'm just trying Acronis in a vm so that I could tell if I could use it on my machine later on.

Comment: If you are just testing it out, just mount a second VDI in the VM. It will be much faster and simpler than a flash drive.